# Disk Memory 100% Asus after removing item

Tags: memory, headphones

After removing a stuck headphone jack from the inside my disk usage is 100%, it was always around 10%. Is it possible they screwed up something? I let a computer company do this.

Comment: You let a company do what exactly?  The removal of a headphone jack wouldn't cause your HDD to be used

Comment: What is "Disk memory"?  
Do you mean your disk is full? (disk usage, disk capacity or similar).  
Or the disk is 100% busy (disk utilisation).

Alternatively, what is "100% Asus"?

Recap: the title is very unclear.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not possible.

There are three reasonable possibilities:

1. Your system is temporarily performing a scan or defrag.  Let it run for several hours, and see if the disk usage goes down.
2. The "computer company" installed something on your computer or changed a setting.
3. Coincidence.  Something failed or is running, and it is just a coincidence that it happened around the same time as your stuck headphone jack.